# Change high chart color for particulaar page

Tags: highcharts

I m using `highchart` in 3-4 diferent pages. I just want to change the `highchart` color. I used

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#f6921e', '#212060', '#ecd222', '#acacac']
   });
```

but it changes highchart color in all pages. I just want to change highchart color on some pages.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts.setOptions changes the color for all highchart object as stated on the api itself

> http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.setOptions()

For changing the color of a particular chart you should update only the chart color option. You can  achieve this by following code snippet:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        colors: ['#f6921e', '#212060', '#ecd222', '#acacac'], // these colors will only be used for this highchart graph
        ...
}
```

> Demo for jsfiddle (modified example given on a highchart api): http://jsfiddle.net/25ye6/